# "[what is a construction]"?

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте.
Объясните смысл конструкции
`var astr = “[object Array]”`
и вообще часть функции из книги С.Стефанова "Шаблоны".

```
var astr = “[object Array]”,
toString = Object.prototype.toString;
function isArray(a) {
return toString.call(a) === astr;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> В JS каждый объект обладает методом toString, который вызывается
>   автоматически каждый раз, когда требуется строковое представление
>   объекта.
>   По умолчанию, если этот метод не перекрыт объектом-наследником Object - он возвращает '[object <тип объекта>]'.

В данном случае `astr` - это просто переменная со строкой, служащая лишь для того, что бы потом сравнить эту строку со строкой полученной в результате `toString.call(a)`

Comment: Понятно. Понятно.

Comment: А почему нельзя использовать просто `a.constructor === Array`?

Comment: @Alexander Zonov, эта книжка 2010 года выпуска, плюс конструктор может быть переопределен.

Comment: @AlexanderZonov потому что массив мог быть взят из другого окна, где переменная Array своя. В таком случае проверки `a.constructor === Array` или `a instanceof Array` соврут.

Comment: Полный список противопоказаний [ТУТ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28467392/7815487)